# hovering over list item, only one item showing up instead of all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HI I am trying to make a menu where items show up as they hover. I am quite new to jquery, css, etc. and I cant quite figure out what my problem is. Right now I do get my div to show up on hover, but instead of just one all of them show up.

How do I make the div tag of only the item I hover over show up.

Here is the fiddle:

```
<ul class="navi">
    <li> <a class='light'>
            Item1
            <div class="hover-name" style="display:none">
                Businesses
            </div>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li> <a class='light'>
            Item2
            <div class="hover-name" style="display:none">
               Agencies
            </div>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li> <a class='light'>
            Item3
            <div class="hover-name" style="display:none">
                Billing Plans
            </div>
        </a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Samfr/

For example if I hover over Item1 then only Businesses would show up. Item2 only Agencies show up

Thank you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Samfr/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the following to show the items:

```
$('.hover-name').show();
```

What this does is find everything within the doucment that has a class of `.hover-name` and does the `show()` function on it.

All you need to do is change the show line to be context aware:

```
$(this).find('.hover-name').show();
```

Using `$(this).find('.hover-name')` will find all the elements inside of what you hovered over with a class of `.hover-name` and show that, instead of showing all of them.

Additionally, if you wanted to hide the shown elements when you move over a new element, you could use the following:

```
$('.navi > li a.light').hover(function () {
    $('.hover-name').hide();
    $(this).find('.hover-name').show();
});
```

`$('.hover-name').hide();` will hide everything with the class of `.hover-name` and then show the items inside the element you are currently over.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed response!! helps alot!

Comment: It's always best to explain things than just give a solution. Hopefully you will understand what is happening better, rather than just using the solution given.

Answer (score 1):

This code is going to hide the other elements:

```
$('.navi > li a.light').hover(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.hover-name').hide();
    $(this).find('.hover-name').show();
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Samfr/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `currentTarget` of the event, which will return the element that was hovered, and you can use that to filter to only show the hover-name of that element:

```
   $('.navi > li a.light').hover(function (e) {
       $(e.currentTarget).find('.hover-name').show();
   });
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/Samfr/4/)